# Use graph api post image on facebook wall errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid parameter

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

getting this response

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Invalid parameter}}
```

My fragment code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext;

/**
 * Created by aditi on 24/7/17.
 */

public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    View rootView;
    Button mFb;
    Bitmap photo;
    EditText mMessage;
    EditText mcategory;
    private CallbackManager mFacebookCallbackManager;
    private LoginManager loginManager;
    public SecondFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_screen, container, false);
        mFb = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fb);
        mcategory = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        mMessage = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        mFb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mcategory != null && !mcategory.equals("") && mMessage != null && !mMessage.equals("")) {
                    List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions", "manage_pages", "publish_pages");
                    loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
                    loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(SecondFragment.this, permissionNeeds);
                    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager,

                            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                                @Override

                                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                                    sharePhotoToFacebook(loginResult);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancel() {
                                    System.out.print("onCancel");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                                    System.out.print("onError");
                                }
                            }
                    );
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "please give category and message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    private void sharePhotoToFacebook(LoginResult lg) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putByteArray("object_attachment",    getArguments().getByteArray("image"));
        bundle.putString("message", mMessage.getText().toString());

        GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "me/photos",
                bundle,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                        Log.d("completed facebook graph req", graphResponse.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), graphResponse.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
        );
        graphRequest.executeAsync();

    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

`getArguments().getByteArray("image")` is a byte array image!!

Comment: adding tags and proper code format

Comment: do you want to share photo in facebook

Comment: yes on the logged in facebook account wall

Comment: didn't get you ... can u explain in brief